# How to center flot graph x-axis tick labels between ticks

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a multiseries bar chart created using flot.js:  http://jsfiddle.net/tFy46/6/.

As you can see from the fiddle, it's not clear which set of bars each tick is referring to.

Even if I change each data point so that each set of bars is centered around a tick (http://jsfiddle.net/tFy46/7/), it's not very clear (especially when the number of series increases.

I would like to be able to center the tick labels between each set of ticks.  Is this possible?  (I've tried `labelWidth` to no avail; do I need to fiddle with a `tickFormatter` function?)

Comment: can add css rules. Look at live html generated. Both axis have good class definitions

Comment: Is this a new feature in version 0.8.1?  I can see the html in the fiddle, but on my own website (which sadly I cannot link to) the tick labels are drawn on the canvas.

Comment: @DerekHenderson, this is mostly a matter of tweaking the `barWidth` and `ticks` array until you like the appearance.  I always liked how highcharts draws grouped bars: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic, skinny bars with space in between each and a large gap between each "category".  Something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/tFy46/9/

Comment: @Mark, unfortunately, that still leaves the tick labels aligned with the ticks. What I'm aiming for is graphing categories (although, as you pointed out in the answer to my other question, without the categories plugin), and the tick marks shouldn't be the axis around which the category is centered but rather the defining boundaries of that category, with the label centered between the tick marks.  This way it's far clearer that bars belong to a specific category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood what you were after.

Unfortunately, Flot draws the labels **at** the tick positions, so offsetting the label from the tick is going to be problematic.

A better solution is to disable the ticks, and then use the grid's `markings` option to demarcate the column groups:

```
    xaxis: {
        ticks: [[0.5,"1st Nov to 3rd Nov"],[2.0,"11th Nov to 15th Nov"]],
        tickLength: 0, // disable tick
        min: -0.2,
        max: 2.7
    },
    yaxis: {
        tickLength: 0 // disable tick
    },
    grid: {
        markings: [ { xaxis: { from: 1.25, to: 1.25 }, color: "black" } ] // create demarcation line
    }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tFy46/11/).

[image]